# Split one Ethernet line in 2 ? Also my provider is saying some IP conflicting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have an Ethernet line coming from my net provider.I have connected it into a TP-LINK Wi-Fi router and one line going from router LAN port to PC.
Now I want to split my main line coming from net provider in 2, where one goes to my PC and other to my TP-LINK router.

Please tell me how to do it ? My home and office are adjacent to each other and router is placed in office so weak Wi-Fi signal come to home, that's why I want to split and put router at home.

Also my net provider is saying that there will be some IP conflicting, I don't understand that.

Also one thing that one MAC address is fixed from my net provider office, as if I connect main line to other laptop or PC other than the one that is fixed from the office, it shows error "MAC address different" on the laptop or PC. This may imply that one line for one MAC address.

Please suggest some solution.

Thank You

https://www.mediafire.com/?xbu5kx3wqbdohuo

Comment: Is your internet uplink currently connected to the router’s WAN port?

Comment: Yes, my main line is connected to WAN Port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do what you want because your ISP won’t give you two public IP addresses. Instead, you should use a router with NAT, which is how your current setup works.

Seeing how you’re probably able to reach both living room and office via Ethernet, you can probably also install an Ethernet connection going from your office to your living room. In your office, this cable will be connected to one of your current router’s LAN ports.

In you living room, you’d use another router or access point to provide additional WiFi coverage. Before connecting this additional router to the network, you’ll have to perform some additional steps:

- Ensure that the new router’s IP address doesn’t conflict with your current router’s.
- (Optional) Make sure that both router’s are in the same subnet (192.168.**1**.0 or similar), so you can access its web interface later
- Disable DHCP on the new router
- (Optional) Configure the new router to use the same WiFi network name and encryption/password, so you can roam between both networks

After that, connect the cable coming from your office to a *LAN port* on the new router.

Of course, you could also use a pure access point for this, but routers are typically cheaper.

If you don’t want to install a cable, you can also go for a repeater. It connects to your existing WiFi network and (simply said) enhances its signal. Due to various reasons, it will always perform poorer than your original WiFi network and it also depends on being able to connect to the WiFi network at all.

Answer (score 1):

The device used to "split" is called Ethernet switch.  That device can split to any number but some consideration is needed:  Your service provider may be happy to allow only limited number of end devices at the line. Each device you connect to main line will need a different ip address --- which is provided by your ISP. 
Your router will take one ip-address no matter how many devices you connect *behind* it.

So, apparently solution is to connect your devices *behind* the router, not split the main line.